# Creating A Section

Tags: c#, json, desire2learn

I'm creating an app that will create a section associated the orgunitid created by the user. I'm using c#.

However, the code below does not work. When I debugged it, the number of attempts is 0. What should I do to send a request and create a new section properly?

```
private void ApiCreateSection(string host, ID2LUserContext userContext)
{
    string orgUnitId = textBoxOrgUnitId.Text;
    string sectionCreateRoute = "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/" + orgUnitId + "/sections/";
    var client = new RestClient(host);
    var valenceAuthenticator = new D2L.Extensibility.AuthSdk.Restsharp.ValenceAuthenticator(userContext);

    var requestCreateSection = new RestRequest(sectionCreateRoute, Method.POST);
    requestCreateSection.AddJsonBody(new 
    {
        Name = "Section Test1",
        Code = "123123",
        Description = new { Content = "Description", Type = "Html" }
    });
    valenceAuthenticator.Authenticate(client, requestCreateSection);
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Did you call http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#put--d2l-api-lp-(version)-(orgUnitId)-sections- first (as called out in the documentation)?

Comment: Thanks for editing, Andreas. @jeffcharles I got it to work. I wasn't executing it so that's why it wasn't attempting. Thanks!